# How to upload image through webservice in angularjs and php

Tags: php, angularjs, web-services

I am working on webservice using AngularJS for mobile application where I have to upload image, I have done Image uploading in web application, but how do I upload an image in webservice using AngularJS and PHP ? I have spent more then 10 hrs for this and now I need help badly.

Bellow is my code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngFileUpload']);
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
                .success(function () {
                })
                .error(function () {
                });
    }
}]);
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

            .when('/signup', {
                title: 'signup',
                templateUrl: 'partials/registration_form.html',
//                    controller: 'signupCtrl'
            })
            ;
}])
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data, $templateCache) {
        $rootScope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function () {
            $templateCache.removeAll();
        });
    });



app.controller('signupCtrl', ['$scope', 'Data', '$upload', '$http', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, Data, $upload, $http, fileUpload) {

    $scope.postForm = function (file, user) {

        Data.post('signup.php', {obj: user}).then(function (results) {
            //            Data.post('signup.php', {obj: $location.search()}).then(function (results) {

            if (results.status == "0") {
                $scope.formUpload = true;
                if (file != null) {
                    $scope.uploadFile(file);
                }
            }
            $scope.result = results;
        });

        //uploadUsing$upload(file, user);


    }
    $scope.uploadFile = function (file) {
        var uploadUrl = "upload/user";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };
}]);
```

I have created one demo form to testing image upload

```
<div ng-controller="signupCtrl">
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="postForm(vImage,obj)" role="form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="obj.vFirst"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="obj.vLast"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="obj.vEmail"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>vPassword</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="obj.vPassword"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>eGender</td>
            <td>Male: <input type="radio" ng-model="obj.eGender" name="eGender" value="Male"> Female: <input type="radio" ng-model="obj.eGender" name="eGender" value="Female"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Image</td>
            <td><input type="file" file-model="vImage" name="vImage" accept="image/*"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dob</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="obj.vDob"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="obj.vPhone"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><textarea type="text" ng-model="obj.tAddress">
</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="obj.vCity"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="obj.vCountry"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

I have tried this and many other solutions but no luck... :(

https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Please let me know the proper way to create webservice if I have crated this one improper way.

Answer (score 0):

On the project I'm currently working on I've used this component:
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload I can honestly said it did it's job ok.

Here's a working example http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/ and here's a working sample using **PHP** as the back-end https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/tree/master/examples/simple

Your angularjs controller will simply contain an instance of `FileUplaoder`

```
$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
   url: 'upload.php'
});
```

And your HTML will look like this

```
<input id="image-upload-input" class="hide" name="image" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" type="file" />
```

once you will select a file from the pop up and click ok the upload will pretty much start. And this plugin also offers you hooks on every step of the download if you want to provide a loading bar or something

Example:

```
uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function() {
    scope.uploading = true;
    progressbar.width('0%');
};
uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileitem, progress) {
    var progressBar = element.find('.progressbar');

    progressBar.width(progress + '%');
    scope.uploading = fileitem.isUploading;
};
uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileitem) {
    scope.uploading = fileitem.isUploading;

    scope.$broadcast('image::uploaded', 'test');
};
uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileitem) {
    scope.uploading = fileitem.isUploading;
};
```

You can also control your file by adding it to a queue and trigger the upload only on *form submit*. You can set the `autoupload` property to false like so:

```
$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
  url: imageModel.getUploadURL(),
  alias: 'image',
  autoUpload: false
});
```

and trigger the upload manually like so:

```
$scope.uploader.uploadAll();
```

API Ref: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API

Hope this helps.

Comment: Getting this error while calling $scope.uploader.upload()
TypeError: $scope.uploader.upload is not a function
$scope.uploader.upload();

Comment: try with `$scope.uploader.uploadAll();`

Comment: this one helps but I have got another problem, in angularjs html forms have some action to post form, but what do I do for form which is submited through mobile (i.e. webserice), I  am creating webserivce (API) for mobile

Comment: I don't think I understand correctly. Could you make another question for this problem maybe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515882/how-to-get-form-data-in-controller-which-is-sent-by-mobile-webservice-in-angul