# How to get form data in controller which is sent by mobile (webservice) in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, webservice-client

I am working on a mobile application project and I am creating webservices in angularjs.  My question is how to get form data in controller which are sent through Mobile Application.  There is a action to call in controller if we have html form but here I am trying to fetch form data through webservice (mobile) in angularjs.

I don't know how to post this question, so please give me suggestion for this question if it is wrong.

There is so much confusion.

**Edit**
Simple explanation

```
<form name="userForm" action="signup/" role="form">
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.vFirst">
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.vLast">
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.vEmail">
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.vPassword">
<input type="radio" ng-model="obj.eGender" name="eGender" value="Male"> 
<input type="radio" ng-model="obj.eGender" name="eGender" value="Female">
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" accept="image/*" id="image-upload-input" name="vImage" >
</form>
```

How do I get form data in controller with action attribute

```
 app.controller('signupCtrl', ['$scope', 'Data', '$http', 'FileUploader','$location', function ($scope, Data, $http, FileUploader,$location) {
/* How do I get Form data here ? */

}
```

or you can use postman rest client to post data to the controller

Comment: so you have a mobile application which contains some forms and you wish to submit that data back to a web service?

Comment: yes exactly the same, and with image upload

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching the problem the wrong way. As I understand, you wish to send some information from the mobile app. In this case you will need a server side web service which will handle your from data and than publish that data via a web socket or smth to your AngularJS controller on your web app.

For web sockets you can use http://socketo.me/ in PHP

*You cannot write a web service in AngularJS, a web service is a server side application which has maybe a REST API or handles request that comes from other clients like mobile apps and web apps.*

Comment: I have written my code in this question -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511340/how-to-upload-image-through-webservice-in-angularjs-and-php/29511893?noredirect=1#comment47186142_29511893

Comment: well to simply post your form data into your controller you put an `ng-submit` on your form. Example: `<form ng-submit="submitFunction()"></form>` and in your controller you will have `$scope.submitFunction = function(){ // handle form data };`

Comment: on every input field you will put a `ng-model="myInput"` and you can access that in your function with `this.myInput`. More info on `ng-submit` have a look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit